# At what time spring create object of a class when it is Autowired..?

Tags: spring, frameworks

We autowire  class in spring framework so that we can call the methods of autowired class to performe some action.  My question is when spring creates object of that class internally.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Context is initialized directly when you start your application by the Spring Framework.

THen maybe you can refine your question if you want to ask something specific about ordering or availability of your beans.

Comment: means that constructor of  autowired class got initialized. when application started so application is going to very slow